# Package-private method seems to not be overriden

Tags: java, classloader, java-bytecode-asm, overriding

I used ASM to generate a super class based on a class `ToOverride`. I'd like to override its `ToOverride::getValue` method. The mentioned class looks like:

```
public abstract class ToOverride {

   Object getValue(String str, Object arg) throws Exception {
     throw new IllegalStateException("PARENT!");
   }

   Object justMethod() {
     return "test";
   }
}
```

In plain java the expected class would look like this:

```
public class GeneratedInheritor extends ToOverride {
  @Override
  Object getValue(String str, Object arg) throws Exception {
    return str + arg;
  }
}
```

I generated the latter class which results in the following bytecode.

```
// class version 49.0 (49)
// access flags 0x21
public class com/example/GeneratedInheritor extends com/example/ToOverride {

    // access flags 0x1
    public <init>()V
        ALOAD 0
        INVOKESPECIAL com/example/ToOverride.<init> ()V
        RETURN
        MAXSTACK = 1
        MAXLOCALS = 1

    // access flags 0x0
    getValue(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; throws java/lang/Exception 
        NEW java/lang/StringBuilder
        DUP
        INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/StringBuilder.<init> ()V
        ALOAD 1
        INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
        ALOAD 2
        INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
        INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.toString ()Ljava/lang/String;
        ARETURN
        MAXSTACK = 2
        MAXLOCALS = 3
}
```

The generated class is loaded using the following `ClassLoader`:

```
class DynamicallyCreatedClassesLoader extends ClassLoader {
  public Class defineClass(String name, byte[] b) {
    return defineClass(name, b, 0, b.length);
  }
}
```

I also tested the generated byte code with ASM*s `CheckClassAdapter`. No errors occurred. When I call the generated class's `getValue` method it results in a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: PARENT!` This means that my overridden `GeneratedInheritor::getValue` method was not invoked at all. But I can see the `getValue` method on the list of `GeneratedInheritor`'s methods (using `GeneratedInheritor.class::getDeclaredMethods`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To clarify what is happening here (this is true for non-generated classes just as much), think about two public classes in the same package that both define and redefine a package-private method:

```
package qux;
public class Foo {
  void baz() { System.out.println("Foo"); }
}

package qux;
public class Bar extends Foo {
  @Override
  void baz() { System.out.println("Bar"); }
}
```

This compiles fine and the Java compiler confirms for you that `Bar` is overriding the method `baz` in `Foo` by using `@Override`. However, to the surprise of even experienced Java developers the method `baz` is not necessarily overridden at runtime! The root of this confusion is the difference of compile time and runtime classes:

1. At compile time, any class `qux.Foo` is considered to be equal to any other `qux.Foo`. It is illegal to define two classes with this name (what is already implicit by the naming conventions of `.java` files). Just as much, two packages `qux` and `qux` are always considered to be equal by only their name.  Thus, the compiler verifies correctly that `qux.Bar` overrides the package-private `baz` in `qux.Foo` as both classes are defined in the package `qux`.
2. At runtime, two classes named `qux.Foo` might not longer be equal. A runtime class is identified by a tuple consisting of the class name and the class's `ClassLoader`. If the name is equal but not the `ClassLoader`, the two `Class` instances are **not** considered to be equal. Thus:

   ```
   classLoaderA.load("qux.Foo") != classLoaderB.load("qux.Foo");
   ```

   might be true if (and only if) the two class loaders do not delegate the class loading to the same parent. The same is true for packages. Assume that the two classes `qux.Foo` above are loaded by different class loaders. In that case, their packages which are both `qux` are not considered to be equal either. As a matter of fact, packages are also compared by both their name and their (implicit) `ClassLoader` of the class they were retrieved from.

But what does this mean in practice?

Consider that the above `qux.Bar` and `qux.Foo` are loaded by two different class loaders. This is legal as long as the class `qux.Foo` is public. Other than the defining class, the method `qux.Foo::baz` is however package-private and therefore not visible to `qux.Bar` which now lives in a different runtime package than `qux.Foo`. Thus, `qux.Foo::baz` is not visible to `qux.Bar` and cannot be overridden by it.

For this reason, calling `new Bar().baz()` might print `Foo` or `Bar` depending on the run-time package of the code that invokes the `baz` method. Does the code belong to `Foo`'s package, the invocation print's `Foo`, does it belong to `Bar`'s package, the invocation prints `Bar`. If it does not belong to any of the two packages (maybe even a third class loader's `qux` package), neither method is visible and an [`IllegalAccessError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalAccessError.html) is thrown.

With this, you are now able to understand what was going on. Your `GeneratedInheritor` is loaded by the `DynamicallyCreatedClassesLoader`. The latter is no class loader of the class that is executing your testing code. Thus, it does not belong to the package of your runtime generated class and the generated class's `getValue` method is not visible to your testing code. The original `getValue` method that you meant to override however is visible to your testing code and is invoked. That way, the exception you encounter is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this problem I performed the following steps.

In case you use different class loader:

1. The base class should be public (if we use default access modifier then our class loader will not be able to find generated class)
2. To successfully override the getValue method it must have at least "protected" access modifier.